# Google Blogger stripping <p> tags, need a way to text-indent the beginning of every strophe

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, blogger

This is a problem that have already been asked here, but I'm not here to ask about how to insert the `<p>` tags.

Let's say in my Google blogger "Compose" editor is opened and I have the following text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mauris est, dictum quis efficitur at, porttitor vitae libero.
>   Pellentesque eget finibus sem. Nam sapien est, accumsan a rhoncus id.
>
> Interdum non lectus. Nullam in imperdiet erat. Suspendisse mollis urna eget quam rutrum, id tristique massa luctus. Donec sodales odio
>   eu ipsum faucibus, eu tempus erat faucibus. Interdum et malesuada
>   fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

And the result I need is this:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam mauris est, dictum quis efficitur at, porttitor vitae libero.
>   Pellentesque eget finibus sem. Nam sapien est, accumsan a rhoncus id.
>
> Interdum non lectus. Nullam in imperdiet erat. Suspendisse mollis urna eget quam rutrum, id tristique massa luctus. Donec sodales odio
>   eu ipsum faucibus, eu tempus erat faucibus. Interdum et malesuada
>   fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

As you can see, there is a space before the first line of each strophe. Fine, but the only way I found so far to do that is manually, and only using the HTML entity `&nbsp;`

What I would like to do is to automatically `text-indent:80px` on every first line of each strophe. I presume it should be a CSS + jQuery script inside the Template, but so far I haven't found anything related to this issue.

EDIT: I can't use `<p>` tags because they will just be stripped by the editor.

Comment: What kind of markup is it spitting out?

Comment: `br` and `div`, HTML4 I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably have to make the rule more specific, but maybe try using the `before` CSS pseudoselector:

```
div:before {
  content: "";
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will change all divs text-indent in your post body

```
.post-body div {
    text-indent:80px;
}
```